# How to hide the code inside an input after user click on Jquery autocomplete result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am making a web application with python Flask.

I am using Jquery autocomplete to make a search field with autocomplete feature.

It works fine. I managed to display icon, images, htmls in the result....

My problem is when a user click on a result, it immediately show the source code inside the  text field and then it open the link of the result.

When I click on "Back" button to come back to the search page, this code is still here in the input.

[image]

I tried to remove it with some javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('task_autocomplete').value = '';
```

It didn't work. I guess the "Back" button is not reloading the page and so it is not executing this javascript code and remove the code from the input.

Here is my Wtform:

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm): #create form
    searchbox_form = StringField('',id='task_autocomplete', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=40)],render_kw={"placeholder": "i.e. : Instagram influencers, Cold messaging Facebook..."})
```

Here is my HTML template with the javascript:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center"><h5>Search for a task</h5></div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    {{form.searchbox_form(class="form-control w-50 p-3",onfocus="this.value=''",)}}
</div>

$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
            }).done(function (data){
                $('#task_autocomplete').autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    minLength: 2
                 }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                     return $("<li></li>")
                         .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                         .append(item.label)
                         .appendTo(ul);
             };
            });
        });
```

And here are my routes:

```
@app.route ('/_autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    list_result = [
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i> P1 Followers of accounts ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i> P2 Likers and Post Commenters ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i> P2 Search by keywords & city ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-telegram"></i> Telegram Group Members ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-whatsapp"></i> P6 List of Phone Numbers ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i> P5 Group Members ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i> P3 Followers of accounts ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-google-maps"></i> P4 Map Search by keyword & city ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-message-text"></i> SMS List of Phone Numbers ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-reddit"></i> Reddit Group Members ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-youtube"></i> Youtube Influencers ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i> P5 Page Admins ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i> P5 Group Admins ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i> P3 Influencers ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i> P1 Influencers ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i> P2 Group Admins ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i> P2 Page Admins ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-telegram"></i> Telegram Group Admins ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i> Influencers <i class="mdi mdi-whatsapp"></i> P6 Group Admins ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <img src=\'leboncoin_black.png\'> Leboncoin Ads ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <img src=\'yellow_pages_black.png\'> YellowPages Search by keywords & city ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <img src=\'craigslist_black.png\'> Craiglist Ads ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <img src=\'pagesjaunes_black.png\'> Pages Jaunes Search by keywords & city ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i> P2 Search by keywords & city ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i> P2 Group Members ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i> P5 Group Members ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i> P3 Followers of accounts ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i> Category B <i class="mdi mdi-google-maps"></i> P4 Map Search by keywords & city ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-shape-plus menu-icon"></i> Authority <i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i> P5 Add Group members as Friends ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-shape-plus menu-icon"></i> Authority <i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i> P3 Auto-Follow ',
        '<i class="mdi mdi-shape-plus menu-icon"></i> Authority <i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i> P1 Auto-Follow ']

    return Response (json.dumps (list_result), mimetype='application/json')


@app.route ('/new_campaign_task', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_campaign_task():
    # Let's get the list of tasks and details for this platform
    form = SearchForm (request.form)       
    

    return render_template ('new_campaign_task.html', title='New Campaign',form=form)
```

I searched for a solution everywhere but without any result. I guess my case is very particular and very rare. No one never post a question regarding this issue.

Do you have any idea how to hide this piece of code?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Include a sample of Return data for testing.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I edit my question by adding minimal reproducible code.

Comment: The field is showing the `value` which is the same as the `label`. Since the `value` is only text, it is not rendered as HTML. I would advise sending a more complex JSON Payload back that can allow you to build the list better and give you a proper `value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to send back a payload like:

`'<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i> Category A <i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i> P1 Followers of accounts '`

I would break it down in JS so that you can construct an Object. We would then have:

- Category Icon `<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i>`
- Category `Category A`
- Label Icon `<i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i>`
- Label `P1 Followers of accounts`

The Object would then look something like this:

```
{
  category: "Category A",
  label: "P1 Followers of accounts",
  value: "P1 Followers of accounts",
  catIcon: "<i class='mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon'></i>",
  labIcon: "<i class='mdi mdi-twitter'></i>"
}
```

You then can use code like this.

```
$(function() {
  $('#task_autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.get('{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}', req, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, el) {
          results.push({
            category: el.substr(el.indexOf("i>") + 2, el.lastIndexOf("<i")),
            label: el.substr(el.lastIndexOf("i>") + 2),
            value: el.substr(el.lastIndexOf("i>") + 2),
            catIcon: $("i:first", el),
            labIcon: $("i:last", el)
          });
        });
        resp(results);
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    _renderItem: function(el, item) {
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<div>" + item.catIcon + item.category "<br>" + item.labIcon + item.label + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
  });
});
```

When Users come Back to the page, they will see `P1 Followers of accounts` in the field as the Value instead of HTML text.

Comment: Thank you so much @Twisty for your help. Your code broke the icons and URLs. I use to see both icons for each row and the result use to be clickable. Now it is not anymore. No links, no icons. See screenshot http://prntscr.com/vjuu2m and http://prntscr.com/vjuv4k. I tried to fix it myself but I am not expert at all in jquery and javascript.